# C++ Comparing data type to variable in "If" statement (if (variable == type) ...........)

Tags: c++, types, conditional-statements, c++17, boolean-expression

How would I compare a variable to its data type in a conditional? When using this in my program (caffeine absorption calculator) it just skips over any type-mismatched input directly to the end without showing the error statement.

Have been moving the blocks around but it seems to make little difference

```
#include <typeinfo>

double cafContent;
...

cout << "Enter milligrams of caffeine: " << endl;
cin >> cafContent;
if (typeid(cafContent) != typeid(double)) {
    cout << "Please enter a NUMBER for caffeine content." << endl;
    return 0;
}

....
```

Comment: `cafContent` will always be a `double`, no matter what input is given, because you declared it as `double cafContent;`. Do you maybe want to check if the usre entered a number or some non-numeric data?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. You can take advantage of the `bool` conversion from a `stream` to check if the read was a valid number.

Answer (score 5):

The variable `cafContent` will *always* be of the type `double`, that the whole point of declarations and strong typing.

What you seem to be wanting is to do *input validation*. This is simplest done by checking the state of the stream itself. Remembering that input operations return a reference to the stream object, and that the streams have a `bool` conversion operator, we could do something like

```
cout << "Enter milligrams of caffeine: ";
while (!(cin >> cafContent))
{
    if (cin.eof())
    {
        // TODO: User wanted to terminate, handle it somehow
    }

    // An error, most likely not a number entered
    cout << "You must enter a number.\n";
    cout << "Enter milligrams of caffeine: ";

    // We must clear the state of the stream to be able to continue
    cin.clear();

    // Also since the user might have added additional stray text after the input
    // we need read it and throw it away
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

// Here a number have been entered, do something with it
```